# RavenDb search over multiple string properties

Tags: c#, lucene, ravendb

I'm trying to make a search over multiple properties. I want to get all the items that at least one of its properties contains the specified *term*. The following code works as expected but I would like to achieve this using *Search* instead of a Lucene query.

```
var t = Regex.Replace(term, " ", @"\ ");
var query = session.Advanced
  .DocumentQuery<Order>()
  .Where($"Property1:*{t}* OR Property2:*{t}* OR Property3:*{t}*");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I asked the question but in the last couple of days, I went over this again. I ended up querying in the way I show below and everything works fine.

```
            var search = $"\"*{term}*\"";
            var qOpt = EscapeQueryOptions.RawQuery;

            query = query
                .Search(o => o.Property1, search, escapeQueryOptions: qOpt)
                .Search(o => o.Property2, search, escapeQueryOptions: qOpt)
                .Search(o => o.Property3, search, escapeQueryOptions: qOpt)
                .Search(o => o.Property4, search, escapeQueryOptions: qOpt);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = session
    .Query<Order>()
    .Search(x => x.Property1, "*term*")
    .Search(x => x.Property2, "*term*")
    .Search(x => x.Property3, "*term*")
    .ToList();
```

Read the docs (select your ravendb version): https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.0/csharp/indexes/querying/searching

From RavenDB docs:

> "By default, RavenDB attempts to guess and match up the semantics
>   between terms. If there are consecutive searches, they will be OR
>   together, otherwise the AND semantic will be used."

And also consider:

> "RavenDB allows you to search by using such queries, but you have to
>   be aware that leading wildcards drastically slow down searches.
>
> Consider if you really need to find substrings. In most cases, looking
>   for whole words is enough. There are also other alternatives for
>   searching without expensive wildcard matches, e.g. indexing a reversed
>   version of text field or creating a custom analyzer."

In previous version of RavenDB it's necessary to allow wildcards in the query:

```
var result = session
        .Query<Order>()
        .Search(x => x.Property1, "*term*", escapeQueryOptions: EscapeQueryOptions.AllowAllWildcards)
        .Search(x => x.Property2, "*term*", escapeQueryOptions: EscapeQueryOptions.AllowAllWildcards)
        .Search(x => x.Property3, "*term*", escapeQueryOptions: EscapeQueryOptions.AllowAllWildcards)
        .ToList();
```

**Update after @yoliva comment:**

To achieve what you want i found a workaround, it consist to replace all whitespaces with a different character in the index definition, and when you query do the same.

Index:

```
public class OrdersIndex : Raven.Client.Documents.Indexes.AbstractIndexCreationTask<Order>
{
     public OrdersIndex()
     {
           Map = orders => from order in orders
                           select new
                           {
                               Property1 = order.Property1.Replace(" ", "-"),
                               Property2 = order.Property2.Replace(" ", "-"),
                               Property3 = order.Property3.Replace(" ", "-"),
                           };
     }
}
```

query:

```
var result = session.Query<Order, OrdersIndex>()
                    .Search(x => x.Property1, "*me product n*".Replace(" ", "-"))
                    .Search(x => x.Property2, "*me prod*".Replace(" ", "-"))
                    .Search(x => x.Property3, "*product*".Replace(" ", "-"))
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks @embri.
 I’m using Raven 3.5. I had a code similar to the one you posted and worked fine while the search pattern doesn't contain spaces. I also tried to use exact match but that didn't work either. I’m looking for a behavior like a contains. For example, I would like to search by order's `ProductName` property. If I have a product named `Some Product Name`, I would like to get a search result if I search by `me Pro`.
With the lucene query I posted above I can get the expected behavior

Comment: @yoliva updated answer, maybe there is a better solution..but it works